# Benefits to using CSS for header image instead of html img tag

Tags: headers

I would just like to find out if there are any benefits to using css {background-image url();} instead using an img tag in the html when setting a header.

I am using the Genesis framework on a wordpress multisite install and by default, when uploading an image in admin>appearance>header, it is sets it up as a CSS {background-image url();}

As I am creating (and learning to create) my own child themes, I find having an img in the html so much better when using a multisite when users customise their themes because:

1. If users don't want to upload a header, there will not be a blank .site-header space ready for the header to be uploaded.
2. The responsiveness - By setting just the img to max-width: 100%; it responds perfectly, always showing the full image, keeping its ratio, and is great for full width headers.
3. Users can crop the header to any height they wish in the admin and it will display the exact cropped height (as long as the width is to the correct recommended size)

I found this code to set it up that took me a long time to find and I would like to share it if anyone is interested:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'genesis_custom_header_style' );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'am_main_header' );
function am_main_header() {
?><div class="header-image"> <?php echo ' <a href="'.home_url().'">  <img 
src="'.get_header_image().'" alt="">   </a>';  ?></div><?php
}
```

But I notice that a lot  of sites such as google +, youtube and I think twitter, when users upload a header image it uses css {background-image url();} for the header (same as genesis by default). So I would like to know the what benefits are there to doing it this way?

Also does the above code look correct? works great for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to HTML semantics, an IMG is a semantically important element of the page while a background image has no semantic importance. Because IMG is semantically important, but might fail to load or render, the HTML standard **requires** an alternative text, a description of the image content, to be supplied with the image in order to be able to display it instead of the image.

The mainstream perception right now is that header images are just decoration and they are not part of the content, and that is why they are used as a CSS property and not with an IMG tag.

technically it should not make much difference in the code as the difference in terms of development effort between

```
<div><img src="<?php >echo get_header_image()?"></div>
```

and

```
<div style="backround:url(<?php >echo get_header_image()?>)"></div>
```

is almost zero.

If you want to cover all possibilities and leave the most options to your users, you can let them decide by themselves if an header image is decoration or content maybe by giving them an option to add a descriptive text to the image and then if supplied use an IMG tag instead of css rules. Some SEO experts might appreciate it but it will probably fly over most peoples head.